# wstring in union

Tags: c++

I'd like to define a union, for reading special kind of binary files. The union should have two members one of int and the other a kind of string, or any other that's the question; what is the best way to do this?

```
union uu {  
    int intval;  
    wstring strval;  

    uu(){ memset(this, 0, sizeof(this)); }  
}
```

it says: "Member strval of union has copy constructor"
I think strval should have a * or a &;
how would you define it?

thanks in advance
Oops

Comment: `memset(this, 0, sizeof(this));` Don't do this in any class you write, ever.

Comment: I don't understand your union. You can't want to have either an `int` _or a wide string_. How can data be either a 32-bits integer or a string, wide or not? Are you sure you're not rather looking for `wchar_t`, the wide character?

Comment: @zneak: `wstring` not being a POD aside, the members in a union can be of different size.

Comment: @KennyTM: I was more speaking semantically.

Comment: @zneak, read carefully my question. The answer lies in the many different fancy file types living there outside in the whole wild world. actually it's a four bytes with four chars I ready it as an int32 and if another parameter has a special flag, it is a pointer to a string anywhere in the file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do it. Members of unions must be POD types - i.e. they must not have constructors or destructors. And even if you could, your call to memset would trample all over the string, leading to undefined behaviour. You can of course use a pointer:

```
union uu {  
    int intval;  
    wstring * strval;  

    uu(){ memset(this, 0, sizeof(uu)); }  
};
```

Comment: Though the null pointer isn't necessarily all 0's. So that constructor is still incorrect.

Comment: For completeness, you should mention that he needs to assign something to the pointer. So it's like `u.strval = new wstring("foo")` and he needs to `delete` that memory afterwards.

Comment: C++0x adds the ability to store non-POD types in unions. But for now, it's POD-types only.

Answer (score 5):

[`boost.variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/variant.html) is what you want to use

```
boost::variant<int, wstring> v("hello");
```

If you use a pointer as member of the union, you have to allocate and free the string that the pointer points to yourself, preferably using `new` and `delete`.

`boost::variant` solves that problem: It allocates all members within the variant object itself (so no dynamic allocation for storing members), and you don't have to do any `new` or `delete` call yourself at all.